# Flask-login: Any built in token authentication? (/hello/world?token=123)

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

I am not interested in storing the auth token in the cookie because I want to be able to send an email to my users and tell them to click a link generated with the token param included.

Where is the best place to put a method that allows users to bypass @login_required if they have a token authentication?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`request_loader`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#custom-login-using-request-loader) decorator that can do what you want:

```
@login.request_loader
def load_from_request(request):
    token = request.args.get("token")
    if token:
        # Validate token, get user and return them here
        # Returning None will let Flask-Login know that
        # you could not validate the user
```

Comment: Sean, how can this be used to get the `current_user` in a view, without using the `@login_required` decorator?  For example, if one mixes auth using cookies or request_loader, like `def default():  print current_user`.  Would want to print None if not logged in via cookie or header.  Thanks.

Comment: The wrapping code in Flask-Login that *uses* `load_from_request` will take care of setting `current_user` for you, in every request.